# Why I do not see devtools tab of ny chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I installed Vue.js devtools in my Google Chrome 96 :
https://prnt.sc/2154uz3

But opening laravel 8/vuejs3 app I do not see vue tab in console of my browser : https://prnt.sc/2155psy
What is wrong and how can it be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Vue.js shows a tab in dev tools.

[image]

Be aware, this will not show if your application is running in production.

NB! You can try this for production mode, it will try build up the same data:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vue-force-dev/oohfffedbkbjnbpbbedapppafmlnccmb